# Where is my sword?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

After completing *Oracle of Ages*, I have begun *Oracle of Seasons* as a Linked Game. According to the article below, I ought to start with a Wooden Sword:

> In a Linked Game, Link begins his adventure with his Wooden Sword, and
>   with four Heart Containers instead of three.
>
> https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Linked_Game#Beginning_a_Linked_Game

While the game did start with four Heart Containers, I'm  now at the Maku Tree Gate with no sword:

> Maku Tree Gate - Show courage to gain passage!

The original Hero's Cave, which usually contains the first sword, has been replaced with the much harder version. And I have explored just about everywhere else.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OK.** So, the sword was in my inventory the whole time. (Apparently, it was given to me somewhere near the start of the game. Maybe I missed the mention of the sword somewhere in the spew of dialogue?)

In any case, the sword was not actually equipped, even though it is clearly the only thing that could possibly be equipped.

Maybe this was my own simple oversight, but this seems uncharacteristic for this series, at least in the previous games developed by Nintendo EAD. (Capcom - what is up with this?)

---

**AFTER SOME REFLECTION**

Started a brand new Linked Game. There was no mention of a sword in any of the dialogue. (In contrast, at other times when the sword is given or found, verbose instructions are given for how to assign it to a button and use it.)

Verified that the sword is auto-equipped in the following situations:

- **Link's Awakening**

  - Shield is auto-equipped to button B when given by Tarin
  - Sword is auto-equipped to first unassigned button when found on the beach
- **Oracle of Ages**

  - Sword is auto-equipped to button B when given by Impa *(regular game)*
  - Shield is auto-equipped to button B when given by Impa *(linked game)*
  - Shield is auto-equipped to first unassigned button when purchased from a shop
- **Oracle of Seasons**

  - Sword is auto-equipped to button B when found in the Hero's Cave *(regular game)*
  - Shield is auto-equipped to first unassigned button when purchased from a shop

Comment: None of the GB/GBC games auto-equip the sword when you get it.  That includes Link's Awakening, which is by Nintendo themselves.

Comment: @Powerlord Well, I thought that, too. But then I started a regular New Game in *Oracle of Seasons*. After retrieving the Wooden Sword from the chest in the Hero's Cave, it is auto-equipped under button B.